# Proving the tower law through an inductive proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

How does one go about inductively proving that

If $K_0  \subseteq K_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq K_n$ are subfields of the complex numbers, then is the following true?$$[K_n  : K_1  : K_0] = [K_n : K_{n - 1}][K_{n - 1} : K_{n - 2}] \cdots [K_1 : K_0]$$

I'd imagine that the base case is $K_0 \subseteq K_1$?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean $[K_n  : K_0] = [K_n : K_{n - 1}][K_{n - 1} : K_{n - 2}] \cdots [K_1 : K_0]$?

Comment: If you prove that $[L:F]=[L:K][K:F]$ for a tower of fields $F \subseteq K \subseteq L$, then you can induct from there. To prove this, think about basis elements in a vector space.

Answer (score 0):

We shall proof by mathematical induction
True for n=1
[K1:k0] = [K1:k0]
Suppose true for n=t
[Kt:k0]=[kt:kt-1][kt-1:kt-2]...[k1:k0]      (1)

We have to proof for n =t+1
That is
[Kt+1:k0]=[kt+1:kt][kt:kt-1][kt-1:kt-2]...[k1:k0]
Now use (1)
[Kt+1:k0]=[kt+1:kt][kt:k0]
[Kt+1:k0]=[kt+1:k0] by short tower law
Hence proved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).